# Rails 3 Error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i got the error DEPRECATION WARNING: error_messages_for was removed from Rails and is now available as a plugin. Please install it with `rails plugin install git://github.com/rails/dynamic_form.git`. (called from _app_views_user_register_html_erb__195833478_79197384_0 at C:/Users/rod/connect-my-friends/app/views/user/register.html.erb:5)

i got the plugin and did a rake but i still get the error did i not do something right?

here is what the page code looks like

```
<%= form_for :user do |form| %>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Enter Your Details</legend>
  <%= error_messages_for "user" %>
  <div class="form_row">
   <label for="screen_name">Screen name:</label>
   <%= form.text_field :screen_name,
        :size => User::SCREEN_NAME_SIZE,
        :maxlength => User::SCREEN_NAME_MAX_LENGTH %>
  </div>
```

i believe that should be enough info if ya need more ask and I'll edit this and add it

```
    require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)

module ConnectMyFriends
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
    # config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
  end
end
```

this is all new to me so i added the aplaction.rb file not sure how to put that in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the plugin's [README](https://github.com/rails/dynamic_form)

My guess is that you should use `form.error_messages` instead of `error_messages_for "user"`.

--edit

Other guesses:

- Have you restarted the server after installation?
- Are you loading all your plugins? Check config/application.rb -> `config.plugins`.

Comment: no i dint restart it still new to ruby :( not sure how to add it to the file

Comment: thanks for the help i got it to work! I had to restart the server and error_messages_for "user" worked just fine!

Comment: No probs. I remember restarting just because I have forgotten it so many times. :)

Comment: this would be much eaiser if the book was written for rails 3